# Swift 2: Image picker crashes after at didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating an app that utilises this image picker code retrieved from: https://github.com/projectwakii/UIImagePickerController-in-Swift

Shown below:

```
 @IBAction func imageButtonDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("pressed")


        //show the action sheet (i.e. the little pop-up box from the bottom that allows you to choose whether you want to pick a photo from the photo library or from your camera 
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Where would you like the image from?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let photoLibraryOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("from library")
            //shows the photo library
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        let cameraOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("take a photo")
            //shows the camera
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
        let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("Cancel")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })

        //Adding the actions to the action sheet. Camera will only show up as an option if the camera is available in the first place.
        optionMenu.addAction(photoLibraryOption)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelOption)
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) == true {
            optionMenu.addAction(cameraOption)} else {
            print ("I don't have a camera.")
        }


        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

        /*
        just adding extra text for fun
        */
    }

    // MARK: - Image Picker Delegates
    //The UIImagePickerController is a view controller that gets presented modally. When we select or cancel the picker, it runs the delegate, where we handle the case and dismiss the modal. 


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        print("finished picking image")
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //handle media here i.e. do stuff with photo

        print("imagePickerController called")

            let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            imageButtonImage.image = chosenImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        //what happens when you cancel
        //which, in our case, is just to get rid of the photo picker which pops up
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The issue is that most of the times that I select an image the app crashes.I think it is partially due to some sort of low memory warning, although I am not sure. It is after I click the "use photo" button as shown below

[image: Image of the camera screen]

Also, does anybody have any idea how I can remove the square thing whenever I take the photo as visible above

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your `imageButtonImage` a valid ImageView outlet ?

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. Once you do this, update your question with relevant details about the crash if you still need help.

Comment: It literally just crashes with no information about the crash.

Comment: It does say "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates." But it does not crash at that point.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
```